# The option "show window frame around device" of Android studio emulator is invalid(macOS with m1)

Tags: android-studio, apple-m1

I try making the emulator showing the window frame, but this option seems to be invalidenter image description here

[emmulator with no window frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLi1r.png)

[the option "show window frame around device"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBZ7W.jpg)

Comment: Same question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347181/emulator-device-frame-not-showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347181/emulator-device-frame-not-showing)

Answer (score 5):

I also tried using custom device frames, definitely not working. I can't ever make device frames work.

[image: Device Preview]