# Emulator device frame not showing

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I installed Android Studio on MacBook for the first time. I installed the first emulator as follows. But when I turn on the device, I can't see the device frame. What do I need to do to see the frame around the device. I am using M2 MacBook.

Creating emulator

[image: 1]

Emulator with no device frame

[image: 2]

Answer (score 4):

On your SDK manager, ensure your that your **android sdk build tool** and the **android emulator** are ticked. confirm the changes and restart your emulator. [skd manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tcyE.png)

Comment: This was the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

[image]

uploading @Ayobami Bababalola image directly to StackOverflow

Comment: "Android SDK" appears to have moved again... as of "Hedgehog" for me it's under "Languages & Frameworks" in main settings not "Appearance & Behavior"